# Unable to Login even after trying correct password

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, ubuntu-gnome, password-recovery

I thought of creating another standard user account but just after I clicked add user it took me to my login screen. After entering my root password it says that it's incorrect. Even in tty4 it does not recognise my password(it shows the password incorrect). So I changed my password using recovery mode. Even then it does not recognise my password. What should I do overcome this situation. There is a lot of data which I need.I am using Ubuntu 18.04 using Gnome communitheme on xorg. Using any other DE also it shows the same. Please suggest me a way to get it done.

Comment: You can not log in to a graphical Interface as root

Comment: I am unable to log in to a graphical as well as terminal interface .

Comment: Please edit your question to elaborate: When you say "it does not recognize my password", exactly how does it tell you so? Is there some kind of 'wrong password' message? Or does the system flash a bit and then return you to the same login screen? Also, please clarify if you are using X or Wayland.

Comment: Edited my description as suggested by you.